# Line spacing and order in title

Tags: titles, line-spacing

I'm using a template I found to write my thesis. In the title page there is a huge line spacing, so it's taking 2 pages. I already tried using \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}, \par after title, \setstretch{1} and \singlespacing, but nothing seems to work. Moreover, I want sentences to be in the order I'm putting them: supervisor, declaration, university, and date, but it keeps appearing as it was in the template originally.
I wonder if someone could please help me.

This is the part for the title page.

```
% Thesis path: /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Princeton/Senior/Spring Semester/Thesis/Thesis_tex
% DOCUMENT CLASS
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,english}{babel}
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/ThesisLaTeX}

% USEFUL PACKAGES
% Commonly-used packages are included by default.
% Refer to section "Book - Useful packages" in the class file "Classes/RoboticsLaTeX.cls" for the complete list.
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{1.5} 

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\hyphenation{par-ti-cu-lar mo-du-le ge-stu-re}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}

% HEADER


\title{\Large{Estimación de la masa del agujero negro central de diferentes AGNs usando espectroscopía en el rango óptico}}


\crest{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{Figures/header_3.jpg}}

\author{Silvia Carolina Rueda Vargas}


% nome relatore tesi 

\supervisor{Ph.D. Beatriz Eugenia Sabogal Martínez}

% DECLARATION


\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{Como requisito parcial para la concesión del título de}

\degree{FISICO}


\university{Universidad de los Andes}

\collegeordept{Departamento de Física}

\degreedate{Bogotá D.C. \\ 2020}
```

**This is the part that corresonds to title page in classes.**

```
\usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{StyleFiles/fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[style = chem-acs, backend=biber, urldate=long,
            dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References/references.bib}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% TITLE PAGE

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%

\begin{alwayssingle}

    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}

    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}

    \thispagestyle{empty}

  \begin{center}

    { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}

{\large \vspace*{25mm} {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{25mm}}

    {{\Large \@author} \par}

{\large \vspace*{1ex}

    {{\@collegeordept} \par}

\vspace*{1ex}

    {{\@university} \par}

\vspace*{5mm}

    { {\submittedtextt} \par}

\vspace*{2mm}

    { {\@supervisor} \par}

\vspace*{10mm}

    {{\submittedtext} \par}

\vspace*{1ex}

    {\it {\@degree} \par}

\vspace*{2ex}

    {\@degreedate}}

  \end{center}

  \null\vfill

\end{alwayssingle}}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: Just don't use that part of the template. Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907

Comment: You might not need the template at all.

Comment: Use a better template. There's a list of them at https://ctan.org/topic/dissertation